# OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Unsupported combination of input and output formats) in getRectSubPix

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Running `cv2.getRectSubPix(img, (5,5), (0,0))` throws the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Unsupported combination of input and output formats) in getRectSubPix.
```

The `dtype` of `img` is *float64*, which was determined with `img.dtype`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking through the source code shows that only combination of inputs for getRectSubPix are:

```
depth == CV_8U && ddepth == CV_8U

depth == CV_8U && ddepth == CV_32F

depth == CV_32F && ddepth == CV_32F
```

This means that the input array needs to be converted to int8 or float32 to be passed in, which can be done with the following:

```
np.int8(img)
```

or

```
np.float32(img)
```

Comment: np.int8(img) didn't worked for my case but np.float32(img) worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `.astype()`:

```
img.astype('int8')
```