# cv2.error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)

Tags: python, opencv

code:

```py
import cv2
import cv2 as cv
import time
from skimage import transform, img_as_float
import numpy as np
import dlib

color = ('b','g','r')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 650)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 500)

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
near_threshold = 0.01
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
print("This is the fps ", fps)

img = cv2.imread("image.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = transform.resize(img, (290, 290))
img = img_as_float(img)

if (img.shape[2] < 4):
    print('sorry can\'t mask')


while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    face_rects, scores, idx = detector.run(frame, 0)

    if ret == True:
        frame = img_as_float(frame)


        frame[100:390, 0:290, 0] *= 1 - img[:, :, 3]
        frame[100:390, 0:290, 1] *= 1 - img[:, :, 3]
        frame[100:390, 0:290, 2] *= 1 - img[:, :, 3]
        frame[100:390, 0:290, :] += img[:, :, :3]

        for i, d in enumerate(face_rects):
            x1 = d.left()
            y1 = d.top()
            x2 = d.right()
            y2 = d.bottom()

            faceLong = y2 - y1
            upface = frame[y1:y1 + int(1 / 3 * faceLong), x1:x2]
            downface = frame[y1 + int(1 / 3 * faceLong):y2, x1:x2]

            hist1 = cv.calcHist([upface], [0, 1, 2], None, [256, 256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
            hist2 = cv.calcHist([downface], [0, 1, 2], None, [256, 256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])


            cv.normalize(hist1, hist1, 0, 1.0, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
            cv.normalize(hist2, hist2, 0, 1.0, cv.NORM_MINMAX)

            near = cv.compareHist(hist1, hist2, 0)

            if (near < near_threshold):
                cv.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 4, cv.LINE_AA)
                cv.putText(frame, "Wear Mask", (x1, y1), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 1, cv.LINE_AA)
            else:
                cv.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 4, cv.LINE_AA)
                cv.putText(frame, "No Mask", (x1, y1), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\untitled1\測試\PNG+CAM test.py", line 58, in <module>
    hist1 = cv.calcHist([upface], [0, 1, 2], None, [256, 256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-m8us58q4\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:1007: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)  in function 'cv::calcHist'
```

I want to know how to address this error, thank you. :D

Comment: This post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453576/opencv-error-unsupported-format-or-combination-of-formats-unsupported-combinat, from a search for the error message "Unsupported format or combination of formats"

Comment: `img_as_float` converts the array type (dtype) to `np.float64`. `cv.calcHist` does not support `np.float64`. You may use `cv.calcHist([upface.astype(np.float32)],` and `cv.calcHist([downface.astype(np.float32)],`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).